# How to distribute different threads to access different links in JMeter

Tags: csv, authentication, passwords, jmeter

My scenario is:

```
1) 6 Different threads
2) 2 Different Links (Login and Registration)
```

I want 3 users to login to the System, others 3 for registration.
I have created a Thread Group of 6 users and using CSV for different login and Registration.

Please help with this scenario.

Comment: are login and registration independent? or they follow each other. like, login-> registration?

Comment: one CSV file for both links, or one for each Link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two thread groups.Each with three users for registration and login respectively.By default jmeter will run it concurrently.If you dont want it to run concurrently and want it to run consecutively,click on the 'Run thread groups consecutively checkbox' in the Test plan's root page